How to effectively group elements in DataFrame and retrieve multiple column values?
I have a DataFrame with column values including "time" and "location." Example:
data = [['A', '13:00', 2], ['B', '15:00', 0], ['C', '13:00', 3], ['D', '13:00', 0], ['E', '17:00', 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['location', 'time', 'other']) 

I want to group the values by time and then call a function with the time and locations. I tried doing this:
result = df.groupby('time')['location'].apply(list)

But then, the times gets hidden as the indexes of result and I am unable to call the function on the time and locations in a vectorized way. It looks like this:
13:00    [A, C, D]
15:00    [B]
17:00    [E]

When I iterate through it or use apply() I only get the location lists. And I need the times too as an argument in the function. Does anyone know the right way to do this?
Thank you!

provide your exact desired output

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the time. I just want to iterate or vectorize over result being able to have the values of the time and locations. I can access the times when I say result.indexes but that is the only way I've found which would be sloppy. Or if I could use result.apply(my_function) that would be good but I only get the locations as the argument.

Isn't it enough to just iterate over the results of the groupby? Like this: for time_str, location_series in df.groupby('time')['location']:

Oh thank you, that helped. Sorry, getting a bit lost in the sauce over here

plz don't describe desired output. show your desired output.

IIUC use x.name for times used for grouping key:
def func(x):
    #get times
    print (x.name)
    #get locations
    print (x)
    
    #sample ouput
    return x.name + x
    
result = df.groupby('time')['location'].apply(func).droplevel(1).reset_index()
print (result)
    time location
0  13:00   13:00A
1  13:00   13:00C
2  13:00   13:00D
3  15:00   15:00B
4  17:00   17:00E

